# How to open in pandas a TXT with space between rows and header?

Tags: python, pandas

In Python3 and pandas I need to load a `.txt` file.

It starts with a header. Columns have quotation marks and are divided by `";"`

Lines with data follow the same pattern. Example of the header and the first two lines:

```
"Cód. Eleição";"Desc. Eleição";"Data e hora";"CNPJ Prestador Conta";"Sequencial Candidato";"UF";"Sigla  Partido";"Numero candidato";"Cargo";"Nome candidato";"CPF do candidato";"Numero Recibo Eleitoral";"Numero do documento";"CPF/CNPJ do doador";"Nome do doador";"Nome do doador (Receita Federal)";"Sigla UE doador";"Número partido doador";"Número candidato doador";"Cod setor econômico do doador";"Setor econômico do doador";"Data da receita";"Valor receita";"Tipo receita";"Fonte recurso";"Especie recurso";"Descricao da receita";"CPF/CNPJ do doador originário";"Nome do doador originário";"Tipo doador originário";"Setor econômico do doador originário";"Nome do doador originário (Receita Federal)"
"143";"Eleições Gerais 2014";"09/07/201617:15:01";"20571108000141";"10000000120";"AC";"PC do B";"65013";"Deputado Estadual";"FRANCISCO EDUARDO SARAIVA DE FARIAS";"27648176220";"650130700000AC000040";"#NULO";"20614471000105";"Direção Estadual/Distrital";"ELEICAO 2014 COMITE FINANCEIRO AC DISTRITAL/ESTADUAL PARA DEPUTADO FEDERAL PC DO B";"AC";"65";"65013";"9492800";"Atividades de organizações políticas";"10/10/201400:00:00";"5010";"Recursos de partido político";"Outros Recursos nao descritos";"Estimado";"GASOLINA";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO"
"143";"Eleições Gerais 2014";"09/07/201617:15:01";"20572570000163";"10000000121";"AC";"PC do B";"65789";"Deputado Estadual";"JANILSON LOPES LEITE";"61275468268";"657890700000AC000036";"#NULO";"20614471000105";"Direção Estadual/Distrital";"ELEICAO 2014 COMITE FINANCEIRO AC DISTRITAL/ESTADUAL PARA DEPUTADO FEDERAL PC DO B";"AC";"65";"65789";"9492800";"Atividades de organizações políticas";"10/10/201400:00:00";"4008";"Recursos de partido político";"Outros Recursos nao descritos";"Estimado";"GASOLINA";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO";"#NULO"
```

The last column is `"Nome do doador originário (Receita Federal)"`.
Then there is a blank space and the data starts: `"143";"Eleições Gerais 2014";...`

The first line of data ends in `"#NULO"`. Then there is a blank space and the data starts again

So, I need to open in pandas a `.txt` file that has header, has separator `";"` and the lines have a space between them

Please, anyone know how to write this command?

Comment: You seem to be pretty clear on your requirements; what have you tried and how did it not work out? There are a _lot_ of arguments to play around with in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this: cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("receitas_candidatos_2014_brasil.txt", sep=';',  delimiter=' ', encoding = 'latin_1')

Comment: this seems like "basic" ETL work and data-cleaning. Without reading in the file directly, this will be difficult to help you. I can read this type of data in just fine with `read_csv()`.

Comment: So it worked: cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("receitas_candidatos_2014_brasil.txt",sep=';', header=0, encoding = 'latin_1')

Comment: But with this warning: /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/intercept/seguranca/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2728: DtypeWarning: Columns (13) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

Comment: Check which column has `dtype=object` with `df.dtypes` and evaluate if it should be a `string` or `numeric` or else dtypes. After that it is easy to transform to whatever `dtype` you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). It will be easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you. So it worked: cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("receitas_candidatos_2014_brasil.txt",sep=';', header=0, encoding = 'latin_1')

Comment: But with this warning: /home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/intercept/seguranca/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2728: DtypeWarning: Columns (13) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False. interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

Comment: This is because pandas always guess for datatype of each column, and this process is memory demanding, that is the reason behind the warning. you can provide datatype while read_crv ex. pd.read_csv(csv_data, dtype={"user_id": int}). This should solve a warning problem.